# How to properly license software under Artistic License 2

Tags: licensing

How would one follow the proper steps in order to license a "package" under the terms of Artistic License 2, as [published](http://www.perlfoundation.org/artistic_license_2_0) by the Perl Foundation.

Is there a guide, such as [GNU's GPL how-to](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html) that I'm missing?

I've only found [CPAN's Licensing Guide](http://www.perlfoundation.org/cpan_licensing_guidelines), I believe it would apply for external use too, wouldn't it?

Otherwise, I presume adding a notice at the start of each source code file, and including a copy of the license itself with the distribution would do the trick.

Still, since licensing is quite an important issue, I'd like to hear any views on this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start, I must warn you I'm not a lawyer.

As far as I know, the way you communicate the license to others is not dependent on any specific license. If you're the sole author of the work, you hold the copyright and have the exclusive rights to decide what is allowed with respect to distribution, modification etc. You can communicate your decision through a well known licence to help potential users of your work understand the terms of usage.

From a practical view, adding a copyright notice to the distribution & copyright headers pointing to that notice to source files should be enough. Also, the licence should be clearly mentioned on the site where you provide download of the distribution.